# Static Text and embed text both greyed out Flash CC professional

Tags: adobe-flash

I have Flash professional CC build 14.1.0.96 and I'm trying to perform a free transform on some text; however when I do this, the text disappears.

Iv'e googled around, which suggests I need to use static text, or if i'm using dynamic text, I need to embed my font.

My problem is that both the static text and the embed font options are greyed out.

How can I either embed text or select static text?

could this be a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using a html5 doc, and one cannot use static text with html5!

[see](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1665048)